# gdb remote debugging: symbol addresses in local file not relocated

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

The following workflow worked for me at one point, and then it suddenly stopped working. I'd like to figure out why and get it to work again.

1. on the host, build binary for target system with debug information
2. send the stripped version of the binary to the target system
3. on the target, run the binary with `gdbserver :6006 mybinary args...`
4. on the host, run `gdb-multiarch mybinary`. This is the unstripped version. It shows that it loaded symbols from the local binary.
5. At the gdb prompt, run `target remote <ip_of_target>:6006`
6. Then, if I say `b main`, it inserts a breakpoint at an unrelocated address like `0x621730`, which is the offset of the main function in the local binary, whereas it should be added on top of the VM address the remote binary is loaded at (0x5555555000 in this case.) Obviously the unrelocated address doesn't work.

So step 6 was working at one point. I don't know what I'm doing now differently to make the relocation no longer work. Help would be appreciated.

Version of gdbserver and that of host gdb are both `Ubuntu 8.1.1-0ubuntu1`. The remote system is aarch64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So step 6 was working at one point. I don't know what I'm doing now differently to make the relocation no longer work.

I suspect that you have upgraded your toolchain, and that your upgraded toolchain produces a [Position-Independent Executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables) `mybinary` by default, where the old toolchain didn't.

Try adding `-no-pie` to the link line of `mybinary`.

> Obviously the unrelocated address doesn't work.

Actually, this *does* work for local debugging -- GDB is smart enough to realize that the code got loaded at a different address:

```
gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...

(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x112d: file t.c, line 1.      <<< Note: unrelocated address
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:1
1       int main() {return 0; }
(gdb) p/x $pc
$1 = 0x55555555512d                            <<< Note: breakpoint worked.
```

It's possible that remote debugging doesn't work, although this worked fine for me using GDB-10.0:

```
strip a.out -o b.out
gdbserver :6006 ./b.out
Process ./b.out created; pid = 239653
Listening on port 6006

... in another window:
gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...

(gdb) target remote :6006
Remote debugging using :6006
Reading /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 from remote target...
warning: File transfers from remote targets can be slow. Use "set sysroot" to access files locally instead.
Reading /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 from remote target...
Reading symbols from target:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/a8/97a1105e21dd270bd418fe58c441700a6d8ec5.debug...
0x00007ffff7fe4940 in _start () from target:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x55555555512d: file t.c, line 1.
```

Comment: It's actually PIE all along. I was also able to get a toy example working, exactly like how it worked for you. But when it comes to the actual binary that I want to debug, it doesn't work. Somehow gdb doesn't recognize that the local binary corresponds to the remote binary. If I set `set verbose on`, when it works, it would say `Using PIE (Position Independent Executable) displacement 0x5555555000 for "<path to local binary>"` after the `target remote ...` command.

Comment: I think I figured out why. For some reason when I run strip on my binary, it produces an output whose program headers are slightly differently from those of the input, and gdb seems to compare the program headers of the remote executable vs those of the local binary to see if it's a match: https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/fd320c4c29c9a1915d24a68a167a5fd6d2c27e60/gdb/solib-svr4.c#L2697-L2701. No idea why strip changes the program headers.

Comment: @ShiminGuo It's a bug in `strip`, possibly this one: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11786

Comment: Wow good find! The problem is exactly comment #14 in that thread, and it was worked around in gdb in https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/commit/be2d111a878e1422c921226bc7714131a5c470fa. Glad we solved the mystery.